# WARNING! ejabberd can not start Admin user is not created Please check your configuration

Tags: ios, macos, terminal, xmpp, ejabberd

My title is my **"error"** that I am facing in the **Terminal** when setup  the **ejabberd**.

What I did.

- Download package from [this website and choose **Mac OS X Intel Installer**.](https://www.process-one.net/en/ejabberd/downloads/)
- I'm following [this tutorial.](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/building-a-jabber-client-for-ios-server-setup--mobile-6958)
- Where I'm reach at `/Applications/ejabberd-16.06/bin` by **Terminal.**
- And run `./postinstall.sh cesare jerry.local password`

And got below error message in terminal.

`WARNING ! ejabberd can not start Admin user is not created Please check your configuration`

But I know there is instruction that 'postinstall.sh' script, which has to be run right after the installation to create the admin user.

So For create admin user I go on [official site of ejabberd.](https://docs.ejabberd.im/developer/install-osx/#registering-a-user)

But there I can't understand **5th** step and my registering process alway in progress .

In short how can I create admin user or how can I remove WARNING from the terminal?

> **COMMENT :** After couples of the days, I found that instead of insall **ejabberd with Operating System Specific Packagesr** you should try to install **ejabberd with Binary Installer.**

Comment: Which OSX version do you have ?

Comment: @Mickaël Rémond OS X EL Captain version 10.11.4

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You do not need to run `postinstall.sh` script as it is already run by the installer and create the admin user for you. If you have had no error message from the installer, you should already be set. You can just call ejabberd start script.

Please make sure that you also approve listening on ports if OSX firewall ask you to authorise it. Ensure also that the user installing ejabberd has admin rights.

Comment: Thanks for your replay! I'm new for XMPP by the way As per your instruction I followed https://docs.ejabberd.im/admin/guide/installation/#start but  'ejabberdctl: command not found'

Comment: there is a `bin/start` script in the bin directory. Just double click on it.

Comment: Yuhuuuu..  has been started... Thanks sir for help me. have a good day!

Comment: But can't able to open "Admin Interface" when i click on it then "This site can’t be reached" - localhost refused to connect.

Comment: Sorry I'm doing first time and newbie for XMPP so can you please elaborate  it ?

Comment: I do not think this error is related to ejabberd. It looks like more general networking configuration issues.

Comment: All is in ejabberd documentation: https://docs.ejabberd.im/admin/guide/configuration/#access-rules